# How to make an exe in mobile that will open my website in mobile browser?

Tags: android, mobile, mobile-website

First of all I am a web developer and I don't know much about mobile apps, so I don't have better words to explain my problem but here is what I want.

- I have a mobile friendly website and I want one shortcut(this is supposed to be downloaded) on peoples mobile that will open my website in their browser. I know there are different platforms and I need to make one for each but for now just for android will be fine. advice is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open their default browser to your website it can be achieved by using an intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("http://example.com"));
startActivity(i);
```

But it might be better to encase your website in a webview to better use the application that is being deployed to the device.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: but can I make and app out of these three lines ? that will be downloaded

Comment: You'll need to create the project and base files but you could potentially just use the three lines in your onCreate method to start the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebView and hardcode in the url/hostname of your website http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html